# How to create s sublist of specific object variables?

Tags: java, gwt, guava

How can I easily create sublist `List<String>` of all `name` properties using Guava?

```
class Person {
  String name;
}


List<Person> persons;

//how can I replace the following using guava `com.google.common`?
List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
for (Person p : persons) {
   results.add(p.getName());
}
```

Comment: Keep your code as it is. It's short and readable enough.

Comment: I know, but it's just an example here, the case I want to apply it is more complex, so this helps a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will do it for you.

```
  List<String> names = Lists.transform(persons, new NameFunction());
```

Where NameFunction is as follows

```
class NameFunction implements Function<Person, String> {

    @Override
    @Nullable
    public String apply(@Nullable Person person) {
            return person.getName();
    }
 }
```

**Edit 1:**

Incorporating @mmounirou answer.

Define you Transformation functions as enums inside your Person class 
This makes it usefull if you will later need to transform based on another attribute e.g age

```
class Person {
    String name;
    String age;

    Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    enum TransformerFunctions implements Function<Person, String> {

        NAME_FUNCTION {
            @Override
            @Nullable
            public String apply(@Nullable Person person) {
                return person.getName();
            }
        },
        AGE_FUNCTION {
            @Override
            @Nullable
            public String apply(@Nullable Person person) {
                return person.getAge();
            }
        };
    }
```

and use the functions

```
 List<String> names = Lists.transform(people,Person.TransformerFunctions.NAME_FUNCTION);
```

But as @ogregoire's comment points out the non-guava way is shorter and readable enough.

Comment: Talking about functions/predicates for properties, my personal preference is a public static final field with the same name as the property, possibly including "get/is". So the "name" `Function` would be `Person.NAME` or `Person.GET_NAME`.

Answer (score 4):

You **can** use guava's [functional idioms](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/FunctionalExplained). **But** you shouldn't. As explained on the linked docs:

> Excessive use of Guava's functional programming idioms can lead to verbose, confusing, unreadable, and inefficient code. These are by far the most easily (and most commonly) abused parts of Guava, and when you go to preposterous lengths to make your code "a one-liner," the Guava team weeps.

The example there very closely matches your use case and shows nicely that the "functional" code would be much less readable. Since it also would most likely be less efficient as well, it really serves no purpose in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer this version of @artfullyContrived solution .

```
List<String> names = Lists.transform(persons, Person.Functs.getName());
```

This solution groups all accessors methods related to your class in the same place 
and helps you to write more functionnal like code without falling in verbosity, confusion and unreadability .